# ANDROID: moving text on custom view not smooth

Tags: android, performance, android-custom-view

I need to write custom view, which will scroll several texts smoothly from right to left.

Well, I already wrote it, however scrolling does not look smooth enough. Here is the code:

```
private Runnable tick = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        anim();
        invalidate();
        handler.postDelayed(this, 10);
    }
};

private void anim()
{
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long dTime = time - animStartTime;
    animStartTime = time;

    offsetX-=(float)(dTime*ANIM_SPEED);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);



    if(rates!=null)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<rates.length; i++)
        {
            Rate r = rates[i];
            float x = ((i*rateWidth) + offsetX + r.offsetX);
            float y = 120;

            if(x>w)
            {
                continue;
            }
            else if(x+rateWidth<0)
            {
                r.offsetX += rates.length*rateWidth;
                continue;
            }

            canvas.drawText(r.currency, x, y, paintBlack);

        }
    }

}
```

It is not very complicated, however scrolling does not look smooth at all and jitters from time to time. I'm not making any allocations during the drawing.

Any ideas how can I improve this?

Comment: The reason may be that Your redraws are not synchronized with the frame rate. Did you have a look to the animation framework (ObjectAnimator, ...)?

Comment: No, I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved better speed by using SurfaceView instead of View.

Answer (score 0):

I just test my code on my device and you can try it. Take your code instead of mine in OnDraw.

```
public class MoveText extends View {

private Scroller mScroller;

private Paint mPaint;

private int x;

public MoveText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init();
}

public MoveText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init();
}

public MoveText(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init();
}

private void init() {
    mScroller = new Scroller(getContext(), new LinearInterpolator());
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    mPaint.setTextSize(30f);
}

@Override
public void computeScroll() {
    super.computeScroll();
    // loop invalidate until the scroller animation is finish.
    if (mScroller.computeScrollOffset()) {
        x = mScroller.getCurrX();
        invalidate();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    // please use your code instead of mine below.
    canvas.drawText("scrolling text", x, mPaint.getTextSize(), mPaint);
}

/**
 * start text translate animation.
 */
public void startScroll() {
    if (mScroller.isFinished()) {
        int width = getWidth();
        mScroller.startScroll(0, 0, width, 0, 10000);
        postInvalidate();
    }

}
}
```

Comment: you are using Scroller which slows down as time goes by, but OP wants constant speed

Comment: @pskink I use LinearInterpolator so the speed is constant